# Datatables "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries" when there are multiple entries

Tags: php, laravel-4, pagination, datatables

Pagination also doesn't work. All I see is the first page of results.

Using the `bllim/datatables ~1.4` package for Laravel.

I've tracked it down to the following code:

```
$Items = Item::select([
    'images.image',
    'items.id',
    'items.sku',
    DB::raw("IF(items.enabled, 'Yes', 'No') AS enabled")
])
    ->leftJoin('images', function ($j) {
        $j->on('items.id', '=', 'images.imageable_id')
            ->where('images.imageable_type', '=', 'Item');
    })
    ->whereNull('items.deleted_at')
    ->groupBy('items.id');

return Datatables::of($Items)->make();
```

If I remove the `leftJoin` and remove the `images.image` field then pagination works correctly but my images don't show. The image thumbnail shows correctly when I keep the join, but that breaks pagination.

Here is my image config on the JS side (if anyone is wondering...changing/removing it does not affect pagination):

```
{
    aTargets: [0],
    bSearchable: false,
    mData: "image",
    mRender: function (data, type, full) {
        return '<img src="' + full[0] + '" alt="thumbnail" class="img-thumbnail" />';
    }
}
```

What might the problem be with this query?